# FIREBASE_AUTH_API is not available on this device

Tags: facebook, firebase-authentication

I have followed the new Google Firebase guide for Facebook sign-in on Android but I am consistently getting the following error on a particular device.

```
FirebaseAuth:signInWithCredential failed                                                                   
com.google.firebase.FirebaseApiNotAvailableException: API: InternalFirebaseAuth.FIREBASE_AUTH_API is not available on this device.
```

On other devices it seems to work fine. The device is Moto X Play running Android 6.0.1. It also has Google Play Services 9.0.83. I tried a complete uninstall and reinstall with no luck.

Comment: Have you figured anything out? Having the same issue with basic email/password auth on Galaxy S6 Edge+ running 9.0.83

Comment: I believe it is a bug in firebase auth. will post back if I find more info.

Comment: Hi. We are trying to diagnose the cause for this error. Mind dropping us an email on the [support form](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) mentioning my name (Alfonso Gomez Jordana)  and with the highest urgency?

Also, you mention you tried a complete uninstall and reinstall. What exactly did you uninstall and reinstall, your application, Google play services, or the device operating system?

Comment: (Clarification: by "highest urgency" I meant to say select "critical" under "urgency" when sending a report through our support form :) )

Comment: Any luck on this? I'm getting the same error. Filed an issue on https://github.com/firebase/friendlychat/issues/32

Comment: Law, could you please reach out to us via the support form? Or alfongj at googledotcom

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was a bug affecting the 9.0.0 and 9.0.1 versions of the SDK. It has been fixed as of SDK version 9.0.2.

Update the Google repository via the Android SDK manager and then change your gradle dependency to:
`compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.2'`

See incident details [here](https://status.firebase.google.com/incident/Authentication/16001).

Comment: I am having this same issue on 10.0.1 (on NOX emulator), which has play services[10.0.84] installed

Comment: Me too, I am having the the same issue on 10.2.1

Answer (score 2):

As Alfonso says in the comments, there is an issue we are seeing where some users don't have the Firebase Auth API available even though they have Google Play services 9.0.83.

That's a bug - sorry about that - and is being investigated at the moment. If you're seeing it, please raise an issue in the [troubleshooting](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) page with any further details of the device where you had the problem.